# Angular + RxJS: Make multiple Server calls within flatMap and retrieve them in subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

Below is the code snippet of my problem.

```
this.locationService.getUserLocation()
    .flatMap(location => {
        // Some code
        return this.searchService.getResults(location); // returns an observable
    })
    .flatMap(searchResponse => {
        // some code  
        // NEED ANOTHER CALL with searchResponse.  --- (A)
        return this.resultsService.getCount(searchResponse.results); --- (B)
    })
    .subscribe(count => {
        console.log(count);
    });
```

Now I need to make one more call in the second flatMap block. How can I handle this?

If I make multiple Calls how can I subscribe multiple results and retrieve the data in subscribe?

**P.S:** A and B calls can be done parallely. They just need `searchResponse` as input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Observable.forkJoin`, which will make the calls in parallel and return once all of the inner observables are completed:

```
this.locationService.getUserLocation()
    .flatMap(location => {
        // Some code
        return this.searchService.getResults(location); // returns an observable
    })
    .flatMap(searchResponse => {
        return Observable.forkJoin(
          this.resultsService.getCount(searchResponse.results),
          Observable.of(searchResponse) // replace with second call here
        );
    })
    .subscribe(([count, results]) => { // forkJoin returns array of results
        console.log(count, results);
    });
```

Here's more info on the `forkJoin` operator: [Docs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html)

---

**UPDATE**

As @ChauTran noticed in comments, if your one or more of the observables do not complete (or you need to get the results before they are completed), then you can use `Observable.combineLatest` ([Docs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html)).

This operator returns as soon as each of the inner observables emits at least **once**. Here's an example with `combineLatest`:

```
this.locationService.getUserLocation()
    //...
    .flatMap(searchResponse => {
        return Observable.combineLatest(
          this.resultsService.getCount(searchResponse.results),
          Observable.of(searchResponse) // replace with second call here
        );
    })
    .subscribe(([count, results]) => { // forkJoin returns array of results
        console.log(count, results);
    });
```

Comment: Nice, and will the results be always in the order we have called?

Comment: Yes, they will be in the same order, as the observables passed to `forkJoin`.

Comment: `forkJoin` would work only if both Observables complete. If you know the Observables cannot complete on their own or do not complete, you can use `combineLatest` instead. CombineLatest will emit once each observable has emitted at least once.

Comment: @Krypt1 ForkJoin is the answer and initially it did not work. After a while I have figured out that take(1) is what I am missing for one of the Observable which is a subject. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Krypt1 One problem. If one of the call does not return then forkJoin is not working. So how to handle these cases. I mean only if one of the call returns output and the other is optional then ? Pls suggest.

Comment: I've updated the answer as ChauTran noticed. Please check whether it applies to your problem. Do you mean optional - as it might not emit a value at all?